# copying all data that is visible with macro vba

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am trying to select all data area where cell is visible.

```
   Range(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
```

I used this vba to select all data in the sheet.

```
Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

I tried this method but it didn't work..

Is there any other way to select all visible data in the sheet with vba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to copy all visible data in the sheet:

- if you care about "constant" (i.e. not resulting from a formula) values only,:

  `Activesheet.Usedrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy`
- if you care about "formula" values only:

  `activesheet.usedrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Copy`
- if you care about both "constant" and "formula" values:

  `union(activesheet.usedrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeconstants),activesheet.usedrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)).Copy`

  which you can write in a more readable style as follows:

  ```
  With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
      Union(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants), .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)).Copy
  End With
  ```

all what above, since:

- `ActiveSheet.UsedRange`

  would refer to a rectangular range whose bounds include all used cells

  thus you'd get both invisible cells and blank (non "data") cells
- `Activesheet.Usedrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

  would refer to all visible cells in a rectangular range whose bounds include all used cells

  thus you'd also get blank (non "data") visible cells

Comment: @HAIZD did yoi get through it?

Comment: Thank you so much for your support. I got the right data that I want

Answer (score 0):

This will only copy visible data in column A.

> Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

Use this instead:

> ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

Comment: yup, Thomas are right, one thing to take note, if your data is too huge. Sort the column A first, then filter then copy the visible cells, else you may have error due to excel limitations.

Comment: You have a point about excel limitations. I think sorting and filtering would have to be considered on a case to case bases.  What do you think about copying the visible cells in x number of rows until all the data is moved. Kind of like pagination.   `pagesize = 1000 : Do : i = i + 1 : Set SourceRange = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Rows( i & ":" & pagesize))  : If not  SourceRange is nothing then SourceRange.Copy Destination:=Target : Loop Until SourceRange is nothing`

Comment: `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy` would include _invisible_ cells as well. Furthemore, It may be not that clear what's OP's real goal since its title is about _"data that is visible"_ while its narrative speaks about _"data area where cell is visible"_. I stuck to OP's title to give my answer

Comment: @user3598756 Thanks